# What if I create iOS App User interface just like Android App?

Tags: android, ios, app-store

I have created one android app which I am going to port to iOS. Not actually port but I am going to create same app for iOS too. I want to user custom views in iOS and make it look just like Android App User Interface.
Will there be issue while submitting that iOS App to Apple Store?

github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift

I am using this library and another thing i am using is
https://s27.postimg.org/etqjld0fn/Screen_Shot_2017_01_02_at_19_18_46.png

Top Bar custom design

Are these two things going to give me problem?

Comment: [This link explains kinda everything you need](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html). btw it will be blocked, you can't publish on IOS with Android UI

Comment: "I want to user custom views in iOS and make it look just like Android App User Interface" -- why would any of your users want this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may encounter problems. While there is a chance you might be able to go through with publishing, there is still a high chance of rejection and a lack of user adoption that would not be conducive to success in the long-run.

Your best bet is to recreate the UI for those views following [iOS Human Interface Design Guidelines.](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/action-sheets/) These are well-outlined and pretty intuitive.

If you're re-coding it natively as well and following documentation this should actually be easier than trying to make the Android style fit and risking going through re-approval after getting rejected. Better to do it right the first time, so to speak.

You can still technically have a custom design, but keep in mind that 1) Apple is strict with their aesthetic compatibility and 2) iOS users will not want an Android experience, and likely vice versa.

If you are not re-coding in native iOS i.e. Swift/Obj-C, etc., there are other workarounds you can look into for getting the functionality cross-compatible, however those UI incompatibilities will still need to be tweaked across the board to meet Human Interface Guidelines/standards.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow